# User allowed to read only one attribute on LDAP using ldapsearch

Tags: ssh, ldap, authentication

Working on OpenLDAP:

```
ldapsearch: @(#) $OpenLDAP: ldapsearch  (Ubuntu) (May 11 2016 16:11:48) $
    buildd@lgw01-10:/build/openldap-mF7Kfq/openldap-2.4.42+dfsg/debian/build/clients/tools
    (LDAP library: OpenLDAP 20442)
```

I have working SSH auth using public keys stored in LDAP directory.

I want to create an user that only can to search on attributes *destinationIndicator* and *sshPublicKey*.

LDAP wrapper script is

```
#!/bin/sh

ldapsearch \
    -D "uid=auth-ssh,ou=ReadOnlyUsers,dc=example,dc=com" \
    -b "ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com" \
    -w "Password" \
    '(&(objectClass=ssh)(destinationIndicator='"$1"'))' 'sshPublicKey' | sed -n '/^ /{H;d;};/sshPublicKey:/x;$g;s/\n *//g;s/sshPublicKey: //gp'
```

I want to limit the *"uid=auth-ssh,ou=ReadOnlyUsers,dc=example,dc=com"* users permissions to ask only for **destinationIndicator** and **sshPublicKey** into the *"ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com"* group.

It is possible? Thanks.

Comment: Possible? Most likely. But since you don't name your LDAP server, we can't tell for sure...  As an example, read http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html

Comment: Access control to attributes is governed by the LDAP directory server, which you don't mention.

Comment: Sorry, question edited to add LDAP version.

Comment: i don't know if ACIs exist on OpenLDAP, but Sun LDAP, we use what we call ACI's,it's just a small policy where you can say for example "for this DN, give the permissions Search,Update on this DN on attributes X Y Z", i would be suprised if OpenLDAP didn't have a similar feature. it should fit your needs perfectly, and it's just 1 ACI to be created (it's easy to do)